# Ansible playbook example code fail to run

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm started to try Ansible, and using example code from Ansible Documentation. After I try several examples, I get error at the beginning of the code. It says

```
- name: Change the hostname to Windows_Ansible
  ^ here(Point at name)"
```

Any advice would be appreciate.

I tried this one
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_hostname_module.html#win-hostname-module

```
---

- name: Change the hostname to Windows_Ansible
  win_hostname:
    name: "Windows_Ansible"
  register: res

- name: Reboot
  win_reboot:
  when: res.reboot_required
```

Comment: Your playbook is not valid. It only contains tasks. Those task should be included in a play. Have a look at the [playbook basics in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below task will change the hostname of the server. Make sure you run on a test server so that it wont create issues. If you just wanted to test some playbook, use the second playbook with win_command

```
---
- hosts: <remote server name which needs to be added in the inventory>
  tasks:
  - name: Change the hostname to Windows_Ansible
    win_hostname:
      name: "Windows_Ansible"
    register: res

  - name: Reboot
    win_reboot:
    when: res.reboot_required
```

```
---
- hosts: <remote server name which needs to be added in the inventory>
  tasks:
  - name: Test
    win_command: whoami
    register: res
```